# Increasing the touchable area on mobile devices (webkit)

Tags: html, forms, mobile-website, usability, bounding-box

I'm really looking for ideas here.  What I need to do is increase the touchable area around an input field so an ambiguous click around an input field will result in focus being given to that field.  Currently I'm focusing on using the touchend event to determine if the user's touch intersects a bounding box around the input field.  The math works out fine but mobile webkit is not responding to the el.focus() method at all.  Does anyone have any ideas for how to do this simpler or workarounds to deal with mobile webkit's focus issues.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the label for mobile when I was testing the click of some checkboxes for Ipod/Ipad/Iphone. I resolved by applying this script:

```
    var iPadLabels = function () {

function fix() {
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label'),
target_id,
el;
for (var i = 0; labels[i]; i++) {
if (labels[i].getAttribute('for')) {
labels[i].onclick = labelClick;
}
}
};

function labelClick() {
el = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('for'));
if (['radio', 'checkbox'].indexOf(el.getAttribute('type')) != -1) {
el.setAttribute('selected', !el.getAttribute('selected'));
} else {
el.focus();
}
};

return {
fix: fix
}

}();
```

Here it is the source from where I got it:
http://www.thewatchmakerproject.com/blog/how-to-fix-the-broken-ipad-form-label-click-issue

Once the label will work, you can start to define an area as you wish :)

Answer (score 1):

In the end, what we found was surrounding the input field with a label/for combo worked great.  Though structurelly awkward, making the label an outer structural element (replacing a div by making the label display:block) gave us the hitbox we needed.  Works on iOS and android.

Answer (score 0):

Using a transparent border to surround the clickable element works if the element is something other than an input field:

```
a.foo { border: 7px solid transparent; }
```

Be careful with sprites in this case, because the border box will reveal the otherwise obscured part of the sprite.